# Can't access my Pod locally using Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod

Sorry for that noobish question, but I'm having an issue reaching my pod and I have no idea why.. (I'm using Minikube locally)

**So I've created this basic pod:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
    type: front-end
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

**And this basic service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service
  
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - targetPort: 80
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30008
  selector:
    app: myapp
    type: front-end
```

However when I try reaching nginx through the browser I fail to do so..
I enter http://NodeIP:30008  .
However when I'm typing minikube service service --url I am able to access it..

**So basically I have 2 questions-**

**1-** Why does my attempt enteting the nodeip and port fail? I 've seen that when I enter minikube ssh and try to curl here **http://NodeIP:30008** it works, so basically while I'm using Minikube I won't be able to browse to my apps? only curl through the minikube ssh or the below command.?

**2-** Why does the minikube service --url command works? what's the difference?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use the external IP address (LoadBalancer Ingress) to access to your application:

curl http://<external-ip>:<port>

where  is the external IP address (LoadBalancer Ingress) of your Service, and  is the value of Port in your Service description. ***If you are using minikube, typing minikube service my-service will automatically open your application in a browser.***

You can find more details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/)